# All command hang with the corrupted file

Tags: corruption, hang

I have a directory `/data/192.168.0.2/mms/4790027` which have a corrupted zip file (not sure it is corrupted?). Everytime i type any command with this file will hang and cannot cancel with Ctrl+c OR Ctrl+z. **(This is a share server)**

When i type `strace ls -l` in the directory, the process will stop at `lstat("4790027.zip"`.

Below is last few line of dmesg

```
futex(0x7f3ca5c1f8f8, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, ".", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
getdents(3, /* 5 entries */, 32768)     = 176
lstat("4790027.zip",
```

If i wan to remove all the directory with `strace rm -rf /data/192.168.0.2/mms/4790027/`

The process also will stop at the `zip` file

```
openat(AT_FDCWD, "4790027", O_RDONLY|O_NOCTTY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_NOFOLLOW) = 3
fcntl(3, F_GETFD)                       = 0
fcntl(3, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)           = 0
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0777, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
fcntl(3, F_GETFL)                       = 0x38800 (flags O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_LARGEFILE|O_DIRECTORY|O_NOFOLLOW)
fcntl(3, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)           = 0
fcntl(3, F_DUPFD, 3)                    = 4
fcntl(4, F_GETFD)                       = 0
fcntl(4, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)           = 0
getdents(3, /* 5 entries */, 32768)     = 176
getdents(3, /* 0 entries */, 32768)     = 0
close(3)                                = 0
unlinkat(4, "4790027.zip", 0
```

This is the filesystem

```
Filesystem               Type    
//192.168.0.2/mms        cifs
```

How can i remove/delete this file Or this directory?
Im new in linux by the way appreciate your help

Answer (score 1):

This is a remote filesystem so there is nothing further you can do on your local machine.

Contact the administrator of the remote system and explain the issue to them. It should be possible for them to remove the file directly from the fileserver